# Run java process as background process in linux

Tags: java, jar, process, installation

I am running my project as jar using **java -jar**  command in Linux machine. As soon as this program run , It produces logs in another directory. Running my program this way requires me to keep the shell open. Now If I have to see the logs , I can't do that in the same shell. I am forced to do that by either doing the duplicate session or new session. Is there any way I can run the jar as background process and see the logs in the same shell ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about it staying alive, something as simple as `nohup java -jar myjar.jar &` should work. If you need it to be automatically restarted if it crashes or start automatically at boot, you'll want to look into something like systemd or monit.

Comment: for running process in background & is enough. nohup command cause to ignore HUP(hangup) signal and continue process after closing shell.